# How can I Automap a missmatch between two models with a different number of fields?

Tags: automapper, asp.net-core-3.1

I use Visual Studio 2019 and .net core 3.1. I have a couple of related models, CustomerCountries and CustomerRegions in a one-to-many relationship, i.e. 1 CustomerCountries has many CustomersRegions.

In the views of the regions I want to show the name of the countries, not the id, that's why I created a ViewModel:

```html
public class CustomerCountryRegionVM
    {
        public int IdCustomerRegion { get; set; }

        public string CustomerRegion { get; set; }

        public int IdCustomerCountry { get; set; }
        
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
      
    }
```

The issue is that the regions model does not have the CustomerCountry field, it has the foreign primary key IdCustomerCountry. So I don't know how to do the mapping, I've tried it but I get a missmatch. One has 4 fields and the other 3. Do I have to make a discount for the viewmodel? or is there another option?

```html
public class CustomerRegionsDto
        {
            public int IdCustomerRegion { get; set; }
            public string CustomerRegion { get; set; }
    
    
            [ForeignKey("CustomerCountryId")]
            public int IdCustomerCountry { get; set; }
            public CustomerCountriesDto CustomerCountryDto { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class CustomerRegions
        {
            [Key]
            public int IdCustomerRegion { get; set; }
    
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima para la región: 50")]
            public string CustomerRegion { get; set; }
    
    
            [ForeignKey("IdCustomerCountry")]
            public int IdCustomerCountry { get; set; }
            public CustomerCountries CustomerCountry { get; set; }       
    
        }
```

Automapping class

```html
CreateMap<CustomerRegionsDto, CustomerRegions>();
                CreateMap<CustomerRegions, CustomerRegionsDto>();
    
                CreateMap<CustomerCountryRegionVM, CustomerRegions>();
                CreateMap<CustomerRegions, CustomerCountryRegionVM>();
    
                CreateMap<CustomerCountryRegionVM, CustomerCountryRegionDto>();
                CreateMap<CustomerCountryRegionDto, CustomerCountryRegionVM>();
```

In the controller:

```html
var model = _mapper.Map<CustomerCountryRegionVM, CustomerRegionsDto>(ccr);
```

The other model:

```html
public class CustomerCountries
{
    
    public int IdCustomerCountry { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Longitud máxima para el país: 50")]
    public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CustomerRegions> CustomerRegions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map particular property

```
 CreateMap<BusinessService.Model.PermitDashboard, BusinessService.Model.Permit>()
            .ForMember(x => x.PermitId, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.PermitId))
            .ForMember(x => x.PermitTitle, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.PermitTitle))
            .ForPath(x => x.PermitType.PermitTypeName, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.PermitType))
            .ForMember(x => x.EffectiveDt, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.EffectiveDt))
            .ForMember(x => x.ExpirationDt, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => z.ExpirationDt))
            .ReverseMap();
```